# Java script to download multiple .pdf files from a same domain

Tags: java, loops, pdf, download, automation

My friend introduced me to my school domain that has learning materials in .pdf format. Though, the site contains hundreds of addresses for each .pdf. For example:

-http://ste.csh.nordtic.net/IMG/pdf/-2.pdf

-http://ste.csh.nordtic.net/IMG/pdf/-3.pdf

Each of the address represents one file

The files I want to download are all the files from

ste.csh.nordtic.net/IMG/pdf/-2.pdf

to

ste.csh.nordtic.net/IMG/pdf/-164.pdf

Please make this script and help me out with your expansive knowledge in Java!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. **We are here to help in your code**. Take a [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) of Stack Overflow and read the [help page](https://stackoverflow.com/help) to see how to ask a [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) question.

Answer (score 0):

if you have access to bash, use this one liner to download all the pdfs to the current terminal directory:

```
for i in {2..164}; do wget http://ste.csh.nordtic.net/IMG/pdf/-$i.pdf; done
```

Comment: How do I use this script? Do I just write it in Eclipse and run?

Comment: what OS are you using?

Comment: I use windows 10

Comment: tbh, I'm not fluent in CMD or Powershell, but the command will work in GitBash if you're interested